# What are the requirements to sniff UDP packets in a Wireless Ad-Hoc network?

Tags: routing, wireless, iptables

In a wireless Ad-Hoc network, I have two computers which communicates in UDP together from 192.168.1.3 to 192.168.1.5

I have a third computer (192.168.1.6) which wants to listen to the packets which are not addressed to it. I can see the packets with tcpdump (which sets the wireless card in promiscuous mode).

To redirect the packets, I am using :

> iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.3 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5

Is it the only rule I need to use? Why isn't it working? Did I miss other requirements?

Comment: Something looks strange here. In a wireless network, why are you re-transmitting through iptables? The destination is receiving multiple copies of the same packets. If all you are doing is sniffing, you do not need to route.

Comment: I don't want to re-transmitting packets. I would like to catch the packet which are not destinated to computer .5

Comment: But you are 'redirecting' the packets ... What did you intend iptables to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you using iptables rather than using good old [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) which is specifically made for this? Wireshark is a free and open-source packet analyzer and the ideal tool for performing these types of analysis.

**EDIT**

If you need to reinject the packets I would have a look at scapy in python.

Comment: I am reusing the packets caught by my filter. Is there anyway to reemit Wireshark caught packets ?

Comment: I would have a look at scapy